# How to include one PHP file, into another PHP file when the are stored in different directories

Tags: php, ubuntu, include

I have built a basic **LAMP** inside an AWS EC2 Instence.

---

1. Ubuntu 18.04
2. APCHE2
3. MySql ALSO USING PhpMyAdmin
4. PHP-7.2

---

- Apach2 sets the root directory for the server at /var/www/html (I
  know, no suprise).
- I can change that root and place files in different locations and when I use the Ip in a browser everything loads dandy, but what I cant seem to do is configure anything so I can load one file into another, with the exception of files sharing the same directory.
- What I want to be able to do is store all my class files into their own directory and use (the include method/function) include 'var/php_class/foofoo.php to load the classes(or in this case the entire PHP script) for use. I have found, with the APACHE2 defualt config, that the include function will never work on a file unless that file shares the same directory as the one you are trying to include it into. Personally I cant configure apache to remedy the situation, in truth I do not know if configuring apache will even remedy the problem

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are the included directories owned by the same group as the web files?

Answer (score 0):

if the dir is  folders up u just need do ../ for each level u wanna go up.
so a e.g

file on /var/www/html/index.php

```
<?php
include '../../php_class/foofoo.php'

echo 'xD';
?>
```

now u have included /var/php_class/foofoo.php

and if u wanna improve go look for namespaces/use and phar

Comment: So that is what i do, virtually the same in 90% of the high level languages, but in my lamp its not working as it normally does. I am pretty sure the server is affecting directories that I am able to load files from, though;  I am asking becuase I am uncertain if it really is and/or how it would be doing that. All I know is in java/c++ even JS I can load classes ussing input 'Blah/blaah/file.php';  In my standard  cant use the input function to load any files from anywhere except from the directory that I am trying to load too.